# Reverse Proxy: serve file from local filesystem if it exists

Tags: reverse-proxy

Imagine the following situation:
I have a distant server for a website.
And I have local servers with a reverse proxy where large files (like videos) are uploaded at off-peak time.

Now I want the reverse proxy to serve a requested file from the local filesystem if the file exists, or from the distant server otherwise.
Is there a simple solution to achieve this ?

edit: For the moment i'm using nginx, but it can be changed.

Comment: What server are you using with the proxy?   Apache with mod_proxy?

Comment: This could be done from the web server. Before making assumptions, which web server are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the requested information.